# empty function not working correctly

Tags: php

I am reading file. I read all data in $part. it is working fine but issue arise when i use empty function. It should display NULL but it is not showing NULL.

My code is as follows:

```
 echo "\nParts------------".$parts[$r]."\n";
                                   echo "\nParts---Size---------".strlen($parts[$r])."\n";
                                    var_dump($parts[$r]);

                                   // $parts[$r]=trim($parts[$r],' ');


                                   //$parts[$r]=str_replace('""','',($parts[$r]));
                                   if(empty($parts[$r]))
                                   {
                                        $entryarray[$c][$c2]='NULL';

                                   }
                                    else if(strlen($parts[$r])<1)  //removing special characters
                                    {
                                        $entryarray[$c][$c2]='NULL';
                                       // array_push($entryarray[$c]);
                                        $valueArray=$valueArray.",".'NULL';
                                    }
```

when i vardump($part) then it is showing its length is 2 instead of 0.

How to display it NULL. i cant write check as if(strlen($parts<2)) cause there is data in file which has lenght less then 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use `isset` instead.

```
$foo = array("a", "b");
isset($foo[2]); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

The empty function check if is null or empty string or 0 or something like that.

If you want to chack if is null, i recommend u to use "is_null()"

To check if a key is on array use

```
array_key_exists($key,$array);
```

Comment: Not completely correct regarding `empty` - it will also check whether the variable `isset`